# How To Set UILocalNotification Soundname in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uilocalnotification, localnotification

We are making an alarm clock app and want to have our UILocalNotification sound be an alarm noise. Currently we can only get the UILocalNotificationDefaultSound to work for us.

We are trying to do something like this:

```
     localNotification.soundName = "iphonesongw.wav"
```

Where iphonesongw.wav is in our project.

Comment: Hey I am having the same issue, were you able to get it to work?

Comment: The issue was my sound was 30 seconds long. Once I used sounds thats were 29 seconds or less my code worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I've read from [Apple's Doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uilocalnotification/1616651-soundname):

> Sounds that last longer than 30 seconds are not supported. If you specify a file with a sound that plays over 30 seconds, the default sound is played instead.